# How to sort woocommerce categories & products without plugins?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have about 400+ products categories & 5000+ Products in my woocommerce list and I modify them regularly so can't use "category and Taxonomy order" or similar plugins and it must be done programmatically.

Need to sort categories and products by name (title).

I'm trying to use this code but it's not working:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query',  'my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'title'; // or name, etc
        $args['order'] = 'asc';
        return $args;
    }
```

Also not this one:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
...
```

Woocommerce products settings, widgets, etc. didn't work for me. 
I saw some similar questions but not working answer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days struggling I came up with a total solution for woocommerce  sorting.

I found a part of solution here for products to make a custom sort option:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/

Which adds an option to woocommerce catalog sorting list. To change it check:

Woocommerce Settings -> Products Tab -> Display -> Default Product Sorting

and select your desired sorting option which you added using the solution above.

Then, for categories (or actually sub categories), add the code below to functions.php :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_subcategories_ordering_args' );

    function custom_woocommerce_get_subcategories_ordering_args( $args ) {
      $args['orderby'] = 'title';
      return $args;
    }
```